# Creation according to Shaivism

Tags: shaivism, creation, shakti

Where can I find a detail description of creation of the universe where Shiv is unexpressed and Shakti is the dynamic expression of the universe we experience?

Comment: You can read [pratyabhijñā](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratyabhijna) , a philosophy in Kashmiri Shaivism where Shiva is prakasha and Shakti is her Vimarsha/ray.

Comment: Many years back, I had read in an article that Siva is an unexpressed element and Shakti is the expressed universe.Wiki article does not say this in clear words.

Comment: I'll post an answer.